# Genetically engineered doodle creatures selector combo

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have created an awesome cheat/fan page for the game [Doodle Creatures](http://joybits.org/games/doodle-creatures/#all) with the help of some cool people in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor). Is there anything I can do to improve this code?

Here is my ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQL_CreatureCombos" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:KJAI_DBConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [Animal1].[AnimalImage] AS AnimalImage1, [Animal2].[AnimalImage] AS AnimalImage2, 
    [Animal1].[AnimalImageAltText] AS AltText1, [Animal2].[AnimalImageAltText] AS AltText2, 
    [Animal1].[AnimalImageToolTip] AS ToolTip1, [Animal2].[AnimalImageToolTip] AS ToolTip2,
    [Animal2].[GroupID] AS Animal2Group,
    [Genes].[GeneImg], [Genes].[GeneAltText], [Genes].[GeneToolTip] FROM [CreatureCombos]
INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal1 
       ON [CreatureCombos].[NewCreatureID] = Animal1.[AnimalId]
    INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal2 
       ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboAnimalID] = Animal2 .[AnimalId]
INNER JOIN [Genes] ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboGeneID] = [Genes].[GeneId]
    ORDER BY AltText2;"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQL_FilterByComboGene" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:KJAI_DBConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [Animal1].[AnimalImage] AS AnimalImage1, [Animal2].[AnimalImage] AS AnimalImage2, 
    [Animal1].[AnimalImageAltText] AS AltText1, [Animal2].[AnimalImageAltText] AS AltText2, 
    [Animal1].[AnimalImageToolTip] AS ToolTip1, [Animal2].[AnimalImageToolTip] AS ToolTip2,
    [Genes].[Gene],
    [Genes].[GeneImg], [Genes].[GeneAltText], [Genes].[GeneToolTip] FROM [CreatureCombos]
INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal1 
       ON [CreatureCombos].[NewCreatureID] = Animal1.[AnimalId]
    INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal2 
       ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboAnimalID] = Animal2 .[AnimalId]
INNER JOIN [Genes] ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboGeneID] = [Genes].[GeneId]
    WHERE @ByComboGene = [Genes].[Gene]
    ORDER BY AltText2;">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDL_FilterByComboGene" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="ByComboGene" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQL_FilterByComboGroup" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:KJAI_DBConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [Animal1].[AnimalImage] AS AnimalImage1, [Animal2].[AnimalImage] AS AnimalImage2, 
    [Animal1].[AnimalImageAltText] AS AltText1, [Animal2].[AnimalImageAltText] AS AltText2, 
    [Animal1].[AnimalImageToolTip] AS ToolTip1, [Animal2].[AnimalImageToolTip] AS ToolTip2,
    [Animal2].[GroupID],
    [Genes].[GeneImg], [Genes].[GeneAltText], [Genes].[GeneToolTip] FROM [CreatureCombos]
INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal1 
       ON [CreatureCombos].[NewCreatureID] = Animal1.[AnimalId]
    INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal2 
       ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboAnimalID] = Animal2 .[AnimalId]
INNER JOIN [Genes] ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboGeneID] = [Genes].[GeneId]
    WHERE @ByComboGroup = [Animal1].[GroupID]
    ORDER BY AltText2;">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDL_FilterByComboGroup" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="ByComboGroup" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <th>Sort By:</th>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RB_ComboAnimalAsc" runat="server" Text="Animal Ascending" GroupName="ComboSorting" Checked="true" AutoPostBack="true" /><br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RB_ComboAnimalDesc" runat="server" Text="Animal Descending" GroupName="ComboSorting" AutoPostBack="true" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RB_ComboGeneAsc" runat="server" Text="Gene Ascending" GroupName="ComboSorting" AutoPostBack="true" /><br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RB_ComboGeneDesc" runat="server" Text="Gene Descending" GroupName="ComboSorting" AutoPostBack="true" />
        </td>
        <th>Filter By:</th>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_FilterByComboGene" runat="server" CssClass="BigText" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="NA">-- Combo Gene --</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Big">Big</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Bloodsucker">Bloodsucker</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Colorful">Colorful</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Domestic">Domestic</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Fast">Fast</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Flying">Flying</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Furry">Furry</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Hardworking">Hardworking</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Horny">Horny</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Insect">Insect</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Jumping">Jumping</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Long Neck">Long Neck</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Long Tail">Long Tail</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Marsupial">Marsupial</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Poisonous">Poisonous</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Predator">Predator</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Rodent">Rodent</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Small">Small</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Social">Social</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Swimming">Swimming</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_FilterByComboGroup" runat="server" CssClass="BigText" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="NA">-- Combo Animal Group --</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Big Animals</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Big Birds</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">Birds</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5">Domestic Animals</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6">Fishes</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="7">Flying Insects</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="8">Forest and Jungle Animals</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="9">Insects</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="10">Many Legged Animals</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="11">Marine Animals</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="12">Mythological Creatures</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="13">Reptiles and Amphibians</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="14">Rodents</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Wild Animals</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <div style="max-height: 128px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <asp:DataList ID="DL_CreatureCombos" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="SQL_CreatureCombos" RepeatColumns="6" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="IMG_ComboAnimal" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("AnimalImage2")%>' AlternateText='<%# Bind("AltText2")%>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("ToolTip2")%>' Width="25%" />+<asp:Image ID="IMG_ComboGene" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("GeneImg")%>' AlternateText='<%# Bind("GeneAltText")%>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("GeneToolTip")%>' Width="25%" />=<asp:Image ID="IMG_NewAnimal" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("AnimalImage1")%>' AlternateText='<%# Bind("AltText1")%>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("ToolTip1")%>' Width="25%" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my codebehind:

```vb
Protected Sub SQL_CreatureCombos_Selecting(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles SQL_CreatureCombos.Selecting
    If RB_ComboAnimalAsc.Checked Then
        e.Arguments.SortExpression = "AltText2 ASC"
    ElseIf RB_ComboAnimalDesc.Checked Then
        e.Arguments.SortExpression = "AltText2 DESC"
    ElseIf RB_ComboGeneAsc.Checked Then
        e.Arguments.SortExpression = "GeneAltText ASC"
    ElseIf RB_ComboGeneDesc.Checked Then
        e.Arguments.SortExpression = "GeneAltText DESC"
    End If

    If e.Arguments.SortExpression = "AltText2 ASC" Then
        RB_ComboAnimalAsc.Checked = True
    ElseIf e.Arguments.SortExpression = "AltText2 DESC" Then
        RB_ComboAnimalDesc.Checked = True
    ElseIf e.Arguments.SortExpression = "GeneAltText ASC" Then
        RB_ComboGeneAsc.Checked = True
    ElseIf e.Arguments.SortExpression = "GeneAltText DESC" Then
        RB_ComboGeneDesc.Checked = True
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub DDL_FilterByComboGene_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DDL_FilterByComboGene.SelectedIndexChanged
    If DDL_FilterByComboGene.SelectedValue <> "NA" Then
        DL_CreatureCombos.DataSourceID = SQL_FilterByComboGene.ID
        DDL_FilterByComboGroup.SelectedValue = "NA"
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub DDL_FilterByComboGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DDL_FilterByComboGroup.SelectedIndexChanged
    If DDL_FilterByComboGroup.SelectedValue <> "NA" Then
        DL_CreatureCombos.DataSourceID = SQL_FilterByComboGroup.ID
        DDL_FilterByComboGene.SelectedValue = "NA"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: have you ever used repeaters before? Actually, You could hold the information in a SQL table and then use a Datatable to show the results. that way you don't have to change the site to add more information

Comment: Oh, yeah. I used them to format the event details for the [Eagles](http://www.rapidcityeagles3555.com) and NFB sites', and People First's Events pages. :-D I am using datalists for this page because they can be laid out in table format. :-)

Answer (score 3):

First thing that I would do is to create stored procedures for your select statements so that you don't clutter up your aspx pages.  This will look a lot nicer and allow you to change the query without having to recompile the website.

I am just scanning right now, but you could also populate your DropDownLists with a SQLDataSource, something similar to

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList1" 
      runat="server" 
      datasourceid="SQL_FilterByComboGene"
      datatextfield="AltText1" 
      datavaluefield="AltText1"
      CssClass="BigText" 
      AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

I wasn't sure exactly what the datatextfield and the datavaluefield should be, so make sure you change those to be what you need them to be.